# best way to bind enum propery in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

what is a best way to bind enum property to datagrid.currently i am using public property and return enum name from there is there any other way ?

**Enumeration**

```
public enum enStatus
{
    Draft = 1,
    Published = 2,
    Started = 3,
    Completed = 4
}
```

**Model**

```
class ModelA
{
  private int statudId;
  public string Status {  get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(enStatus),statudId); }
}
```

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrdAssignments" Style="{StaticResource dataGridManageScreens}" SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrdAssignments_SelectedCellsChanged">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Status}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource gridElementStyle}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource gridEditElementStyle}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach works, but I'd prefer cleaning up your ViewModel by using a binding converter instead.

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Enum)value).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return  null;
    }
}
```

And in your XAML, something like this:

```
Binding="{Binding Status, Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=enumConverter}}"
```

Don't forget to declare your "enumConverter" (or however you'll decide to name it) in the resources section of your xaml file.

Comment: note, that you don't need converter for each `enum` type.  cast to base class `Enum` works fine: `((Enum)value).ToString()`

Comment: cast through enStatus is working but invalid cast exception through in case of enum `return ((Enum)value).ToString()`

Comment: What's the exception saying?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Enum'

Comment: Make sure to bind on an enum (e.g.: public enStatus CurrentStatus {get;set;}) and not a int like public int statudId.

Comment: add ; at  end of  return ((Enum)value).ToString();