# How to bind two Enum property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to bind two properties so I can change the background color in DataGrid based on their value. Based on these answers

1. [How to bind an enum to a combobox control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf)
2. [best way to bind enum propery in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602776/best-way-to-bind-enum-propery-in-datagrid)

I have implemented the advice in my code, but I'm missing something and it doesn't work.
Thanks for any advices.

```cs
namespace Example
{

    public class ExampleClass
    {

        private ExampleObject exampleObject;

        public ExampleObject ExampleObject { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Object
{
    public class ExampleObject
    {

        private Value value;
        public ExampleObject ExampleObject { get; set; }

    }
    public enum Value
    {
        High,
        Low
    }
}
```

> Wpf DataGrid DataTrigger where I am changing the colour

```xml
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExampleObject.Value}" Value="{StaticResource CellConverter}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green">

                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExampleObject.Value}" Value="{StaticResource CellConverter}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">

                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>


            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

> CellConvertor class

```cs
    public class CellConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Value input = ((Value)value);
            switch (input)
            {
                case Value.High:
                    return "High";

                case Value.Low:
                    return "Low";
                default:
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Value="{StaticResource CellConverter}"` - this doesn't make sense. change it to `Value="High"`/`Value="Low"`

Comment: I thought  in case `Value.High return "High"` will appear in `Value` property

Comment: Converter works like that only with bindings

Comment: It still does not solve my problem or I am missing something?

Comment: I don't know, you are missing [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fix the trigger condition in your example.

Additionally, in order to bind to the `ExampleObject.Value` enum value, the `ExampleObject.Value` *must* be a `public` **property**:

```cs
public class ExampleObject 
{
  public Value Value {get; set;}
}
```

In XAML you reference `enum` values like static variables and constants by using the `x:Static` markup extension. In fact, C# `enum` is implemented as a set of constants. When using the `x:Static` extension, your current value converter `CellConverter` becomes obsolete:

```xml
<!-- 
  In this example the namespace that defines the enum type 'Value' 
  is assumed to be registered under the XAML alias 'local' 
-->
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExampleObject.Value}" 
                   Value="{x:Static local:Value.Low}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
      </DataTrigger>

      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExampleObject.Value}" 
                   Value="{x:Static local:Value.High}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**Remarks**: in general, if you want to use a value converter, then you must configure the `Binding` accordingly and assign the `IValueConverter` instance to the `Binding.Converter` property. You can't assign a `IValueConverter` directly to a property to make it convert. The `IValueConverter` must receive an input that he can convert to produce the output. The input is the value provided by the actual `Binding` (and that's why `Binding` has a `Binding.Converter` property - they always go in tandem).

See [Microsoft Docs: DataBinding Overview (Data conversion)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#data-conversion)

Note, since the property `DataTrigger.Value` is not a `DependencyProperty`, you can't define its value via a `Binding`.

Converter example:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <MyValueConverter x:Name="MyValueConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <SomeObject SomeDependencyProperty="{Binding SourceProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}}" />
</Window>
```

It's also recommende best practice to define a default enum value to avoid errors. The default value for an enum instance is always `0` which in your case would default to `High`. Better allow to identify an unset state by adding an explicit `0` value named `None` or `Default`:

```cs
public enum Value
{
  None = 0,
  High,
  Low
}
```

See: [Microsoft Docs: Enum Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum)